# Why does SQL Server require a TOP statement to use ORDER BY?

Tags: sql-server

Why does SQL Server require you to include TOP (whatever) in a View with an ORDER BY statement? Why no just allow you to select all the records (TOP 100 PERCENT) by default?

Comment: Because a view is essentially just the result of a query, to be used in another query. It's comparable with a subquery in that respect; you can't use `order by` without a `top` there either. Why *would* you order it? You can't order a true table either (not really anyway). The reason you can use it with `top`, of course, is because that fundamentally changes the result set.

Comment: TOP + ORDER BY is focused on the TOP part not the ORDER BY part - i.e ORDER BY is allowed to describe the rows you want TOP to return.  ORDER BY with no TOP (or 100%) is fairly meaningless as `select * from vw` will not honour the internal ORDER BY.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm misunderstanding. Let's say I build a View on my server, and the intent is to have my front end application display the results in a report or whatever. So I want to 

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY CUSTOMERLASTNAME

I could simply create an ODBC "link" to this View (say, in MS Access or whatever) to use it as the basis for the report. I'd prefer to let the Server do the sorting because I would think it would run faster than having the records brought to my application is any old order and then have my application have to sort them.

Comment: If you want sorted results from a view you need to order by "outside it" -  `select * from vw order by f`  If you want it all on the server use a procedure.

Comment: I wouldn't ever use SELECT * from a TABLE for a view definition... if the table columns change, your view is wack.

Comment: I wasn't actually using SELECT * that was just a shortcut for my example.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` in a view is not honored for result set ordering. The only purpose of `ORDER BY` in a view is to determine which rows qualify in conjunction with a `TOP` clause. So you must specify TOP when ORDER BY is specified in a view.

If you want SQL Server to order the results, specify `ORDER BY` in the query that selects from the view. Otherwise, you'll need to sort in the app code.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wishing I could avoid that so the server would do it and save having the app have to do it because it's much slower. And using a stored procedure is a bit more of a hassle because in, say, MS Access, you can use ODBC to link to a View on the server as though it were a table, but you can't do that with an SP.

Comment: @BrianBattles, the server will do the ordering when the client specifies ORDER BY in the query.Have you considered a table-valued function that returns an ordered result instead of a view? Not sure about linking a TVF in Access, though. Maybe you could encapsulate the TVF select in a view to work-around Access restrictions.